# How to move a woocommerace site over from http to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, woocommerce, ssl-certificate

Ive recently installed a SSL on to my website and now I have duplicate content at http and https. Im running wordpress with woocommerace and I want to whole site to just run https. How to I go about changing this to only show https content. Im guessing its related to the .htaccess file with a redirect but im not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks but got a Internal Server Error

Comment: Eish. Unlucky. I copied and pasted from my live site.

Comment: Thanks Ive used a plug_in in the end to fix the issue